# Modelling existing database relation in GORM, with composite keys

Tags: mysql, database, grails, constraints, grails-orm

I have this database relation in an old project of mine
where an athletic facility has fields for different sports to book. Mostly football; five a side. 
Some of these facilities have what I call composite fields. Let's take an example. Facility **'4'** has *3* fields for five-a-side football; let's identify them with numbers *1, 2, 3*. These are positioned in such a way that the manager can remove one of the separators and combine two of them to make a field for seven-a-side or both and make a filed for ten-a-side. So, field 4 would be *1+2*, field 5 would be *2+3* and field 6 would *1+2+3*
This is the SQL code I had (This is an old project of mine written in PHP and MySQL).

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS field (
    id              INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    facility_id     INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    internal_id     INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    field_size      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    field_type      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    is_composite    BOOLEAN         NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    display_name    VARCHAR(20)     NULL,


    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (facility_id, internal_id),

    CONSTRAINT fk_field_facility_id FOREIGN KEY (facility_id) REFERENCES facility(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
;

INSERT INTO field (id, facility_id, internal_id, field_size, field_type, is_composite) VALUES
    (4, 4, 1, 'FIVE_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', false),
    (5, 4, 2, 'FIVE_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', false),
    (6, 4, 3, 'FIVE_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', false),
    (7, 4, 4, 'SEVEN_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', true),
    (8, 4, 5, 'SEVEN_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', true),
    (9, 4, 6, 'TEN_ASIDE', 'PLASTIC', true)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS field_component (
    id                      INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    facility_id             INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    composite_internal_id   INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    child_internal_id       INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,


    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY unq_facility_component_child (facility_id, composite_internal_id, child_internal_id),


    CONSTRAINT fk_field_component_field_child FOREIGN KEY (facility_id, child_internal_id) REFERENCES field(facility_id, internal_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_field_component_field_component FOREIGN KEY (facility_id, composite_internal_id) REFERENCES field(facility_id, internal_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
;

INSERT INTO field_component (id, facility_id, composite_internal_id, child_internal_id) VALUES
    (1, 4, 4, 1),
    (2, 4, 4, 2),

    (3, 4, 5, 2),
    (4, 4, 5, 3),

    (5, 4, 6, 1),
    (6, 4, 6, 2),
    (7, 4, 6, 3)
;
```

I am trying to write this project in Grails 3 with GORM for learning reasons (I am using these in my new job, and also if possible I want to recreate the project and offer it to some people). 
As you can see here I have two constraints in the **field_component** so the *parent* field is referenced by the existing fields in **field** but also so that *child* field is referenced by the existing fields in **field** and also belongs in the same facility. So some one can't add a field as a component from a different facility.

In Grails I decided to try to create the domains programmatically and and let GORM create the database (I actually struggled with this, I always preferred to start from the DB and let that guide the development but then again never used ORM before) but I am having issues recreating this constraints.

My table field_component was basically a join table so I am using the hasMany mapping with a joinTable but the problem is that by using the id's I can't enforce the second constraint that makes sure that the child filed is part of the same facility.

Here is my Grails code

```
class Facility {

    String name

    static hasMany = [fields: Field]

    static constraints = {
        name unique: true, blank: false, maxSize: 30
    }
}

class Field {

    int internalId
    FieldType fieldType
    FieldSize fieldSize
    boolean isComposite

    static belongsTo = [facility: Facility]

    static hasMany = [fieldComponents: Field]

    static mapping = {
        fieldComponents joinTable: [name  : "field_component",
                                    key   : "composite_field_id",
                                    column: "child_field_id"]
    }

    static constraints = {
        internalId min: 1, unique: 'facility'
        fieldType blank: false, defaultValue: FieldType.ARTIFICIAL
        fieldSize blank: false, defaultValue: FieldSize.FIVE_A_SIDE
        isComposite defaultValue: false
    }
}
```

I was thinking of using a component id key (instead of the default id).
Then I would have a *facility_id* and *internal_id* as primary key and I think I can reference that in the joinTanble like this:

```
static mapping = {
        fieldComponents joinTable: [name  : "field_component",
                                    key   : "facility_id, internal_id",
                                    column: "child_field_id"]
    }
```

but I am actually not 100% sure this would work. *facility_id* is created by convention in the database but I am not sure how smart GORM is.
Even so, I am still not sure how I would go enforcing the second constraint about the field belonging in the same facility.
Is this something that maybe I shouldn't bother, too effort for the gains? I could put some validation when adding and saving a field but database-wise it would allow for erroneous data.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure double check with this plugin:

https://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer

This plugin creates you groovy classes based on a database model